# Как в "use" и "namespace" указать точный путь?

Tags: php

Есть `autoload` формата, в нём написано

```
use cat\app\models\Auth;
use cat\app\models\Ajax;
use cat\app\models\Admin;
use cat\app\libs\PlayerInfo;
use cat\app\libs\Pagination;
use cat\app\libs\Search;


spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
$path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class.'.php');
if (file_exists($path)) {
    require $path;
}
});
```

(в некоторых файлах и `namespace` есть)
Проблема в том что по сути- в корне- всё нормально, а когда к примеру ссылаешься на этот `autoload`- то запрашивает в том корне, тоесть:
Есть к примеру `site.com/as.php` - если с него запрашиваешь-всё нормально.
Если ты ссылаешься с `site.com/info/index.php` -то оно ищет в самом `info`.
Хотелось бы от вас узнать как правильно указать, и как правильно на примере сделать.
Ещё более детально объясню, если тот же `autoload` использовать в `/info/`-будет искать `/info/cat/...`, а не `site.com/cat/`

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` в помощь.

Comment: Еще кстати можно перейти на composer и почитать стандартъ "PSR-4 автозагрузка"

Comment: @u_mulder, вот что получилось `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in ` в этой строке `use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']\cat\app\models\Auth;`. Если я не правильно вас понял, или не правильно сделал- извините)

Comment: @u_mulder, я вам вроде указал уже, обновите страницу

Comment: Вы бы хоть вывели значение `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` чтобы понять что это а не бездумно подставляли куда ни попадя.

Comment: @u_mulder Это путь к корню сайта, я делал echo, да и было понятно по `document_root`